# How to delete last character from output in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

Suppose my code is

```
void main()
{
    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    { 
        printf("%d, ",i);
    }
}
```

The output of this program will be

```
1, 2, 3, 4,
```

How can I get output like

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

The last `,` should be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an if statement. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for ( int i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
    { 
        if ( i != 1 ) printf( ", " );
        printf( "%d", i );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Or for outputting a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "1234";
    
    for ( const char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( p != s ) printf( ", " );
        putchar( *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Again the program output is

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Your first one is easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%d", pad, i);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

You can't "delete" the character once you've printed it.  You have to code so that you don't print what isn't actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

By using if and else....!!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
        if(i==4){
            printf("%d",i);
        }
        else{
        printf("%d, ",i);}
    
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too many magic numbers for comfort — 0 and 1 aren't usually magic, but most others are.  You should use something like `enum { MAX_NUMBER = 5 };` and then `for (int i = 1; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++)` and `if (i == MAX_NUMBER - 1)`.  It is then clearer how the values 5 and 4 are related.